# Expandable Listview on right of view in android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I want to change my expandable listview.
Before change:

[image]

after  change :

[image]

Please guide me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Shahzade Shahzade! Although you did describe your problem, it is difficult to help you without knowing what your code looks like. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ExpandableListView#setIndicatorBounds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setIndicatorBounds%28int,%20int%29) to change where the indicator shows up. To place it on the left, you'd use `0` for the left position, and the indicator's width for the right.

Comment: Can you give me a example?